# How to set the rowHeight of the first cell in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, row-height

I would like to change the height of the first (top = index 0) cell in a table view, keeping the height of all other cells the same.

**How can I do this?**

Ideally I would like to be able to do this here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   if shouldDisplaySuggestions && indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "help"
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "SFCompactDisplay-Semibold", size: 17)

        return cell
    }
```

I set all other cells like:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 64.07
```

And this does not exist ->

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)).row...
```

Comment: This is what the `heightForRowAt` method is for.

Comment: Why a row height of `64.07`? Why not just `64`?

Comment: I like perfection in my designs, although I think it defaults to that anyway in which case I might as well right? @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement delegate method `heightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return indexPath.row == 0 ? 200 : 100
}
```

You could return dynamic for other cells also if you want to with

```
return indexPath.row == 0 ? 200 : UITableView.automaticDimension
```

---

**Tip** instead of

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Always use

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)!
```

Comment: Given that the OP is setting `rowHeight` of the table view, it might be better to use `return indexPath.row == 0 ? 200 : tableView.rowHeight`